# jQuery UI Sortable -- How can I cancel the click event on an item that's dragged/sorted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a [jQuery UI Sortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable) list. The sortable items also have a click event attached. Is there a way to prevent the click event from firing after I drag an item?

```js
$().ready( function () { 
 $('#my_sortable').sortable({
   update: function() { console.log('update') },
   delay: 30
 });    

 $('#my_sortable li').click(function () {    
   console.log('click');
 });                        

});
```

```css
#my_sortable li {
          border: 1px solid black;
          display: block;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;    
          background-color: gray;
        }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<ul id="my_sortable">                 
  <li id="item_1">A</li>
  <li id="item_2">B</li>
  <li id="item_3">C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now that browsers and jqueryui have had some time to evolve (compensate?) this behavior is only evident in Firefox (47.0). Modern Chrome and IE do not fire the `click` event after `sortable`.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

I had the same problem and since my sortable items contained three or four clickable items (and the number was variable) binding/unbinding them on the fly didn't really seem an option. However, by incident I specified the

```
helper : 'clone'
```

option, which behaved identically to the original sortable in terms of interface but apparently does not fire click events on the dragged item and thus solves the problem. It's as much a hack as anything else, but at least it's short and easy..

Comment: [Levi Crain](http://stackoverflow.com/users/577743/levi-crain) says: "the "helper : 'clone'" trick doesn't work in chrome. The onclick event doesn't fire ever."

Comment: Definitely the best answer! I love simple solutions. The code in the previous answer (selected answer) is clever, but challenging to maintain long term, especially with new programmers trying to figure out clever code.

Comment: I had a problem with combining sortable and Magnific Popup. After dragging an element, the popup would show. This was like a gift from God, after I struggled with the problem for a couple of hours.

Comment: IMHO It's **not** a hack, it's just a smart solution: `helper` defines the DOMElement to show in drag. `clone` uses a clone of the "in-sort-element". Hence, using a clone, actually breaks the "click" check of down+up, then the click event is not fired. So I think this solution is licit and safe.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a reference to the click event for your li, you can unbind it in the sortable update method then use Event/one to rebind it. The event propagation can be stopped before you rebind, preventing your original click handler from firing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head> 


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var myClick = function () {
        console.log('click');
    };

    $().ready( function () { 

       $('#my_sortable').sortable({
         update: function(event, ui) { 
            ui.item.unbind("click");
            ui.item.one("click", function (event) { 
                console.log("one-time-click"); 
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                $(this).click(myClick);
            }); 
            console.log('update') },
         delay: 30
       });    


       $('#my_sortable li').click(myClick);                        

     });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #my_sortable li {
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;    
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

      <ul id="my_sortable">                 
        <li id="item_1">A</li>
        <li id="item_2">B</li>
        <li id="item_3">C</li>
      </ul>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great implementation of one! :)

Comment: This is almost perfect, however if you perform a failed drag it still does the click function. Any thoughts? :(

Answer (score 3):

If you for some reason don't want to use the `helper:'clone'` trick, this worked for me. It cancels the click event on an item that is dragged. jQuery adds the class `ui-sortable-helper` to the dragged element.

```
$('.draggable').click(clickCancelonDrop);
function clickCancelonDrop(event) {
    var cls = $(this).attr('class');
    if (cls.match('ui-sortable-helper'))
         return event.stopImmediatePropagation() || false;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `draggable` coming from? I thought this was about `sortable`. Indeed, `$('.draggable')` to an empty list for me.

Comment: ´.sortable´ is the container list all items inside it are ´.draggable´

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        // event.toElement is the element that was responsible
        // for triggering this event. The handle, in case of a draggable.
        $( event.toElement ).one('click', function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation(); } );
    }
});
```

This works because *"one-listeners"* are fired **before** *"normal"* listeners. So if a one-listener stops propagation, it will never reach your previously set listeners.

Comment: Problem is if the browser never fires the click event during drag, this will prevent the first 'real' click event

Comment: For Firefox 42.0, I cannot confirm that `on` listeners fired after `one` listeners. In fact, my `on` listener is still invoked priorly to my `one` listener.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use a flag on the stop event that and check that flag on the click event.

```
var isSortableCalled = false;

$('#my_sortable').sortable({
         stop: function(event, ui){
              isSortableCalled = true;
         },
         update: function() { console.log('update') },
         delay: 30
});

$('#my_sortable li').click(function () {    
       if(!isSortableCalled){
            console.log('click');
       }
       isSortableCalled = false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by mercilor worked for me a couple of caveats.  The click event was actually on the handle element rather than the sorted item itself.  Unfortunately the ui object, doesn't give you a reference to the handle in the update event (feature request to jquery ui?).  So I had to get the handle myself.  Also, I had to call preventDefault as well to stop the click action.

```
update: function(ev, ui) {
    var handle = $(ui.item).find('h3');
    handle.unbind("click");
    handle.one("click", function (event) {
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                            event.preventDefault();
                            $(this).click(clickHandler);
                        });
    // other update code ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Easier, use a var to know when the element is being sorted...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head> 


  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $().ready( function () {    
       $('#my_sortable').sortable({
         start: function() {
            sorting = true;
         },
         update: function() {
            console.log('update');
            sorting = false;
         },
         delay: 30
       });    


       $('#my_sortable li').click(function () {
         if (typeof(sorting) == "undefined" || !sorting) {
            console.log('click');
         }
       });                        

     });
  </script>

  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #my_sortable li {
      border: 1px solid black;
      display: block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;    
      background-color: gray;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

      <ul id="my_sortable">                 
        <li id="item_1">A</li>
        <li id="item_2">B</li>
        <li id="item_3">C</li>
      </ul>   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Elte Hupkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358873/elte-hupkes);

```
helper: 'clone'
```

I have implemented the same and a sample is shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#MenuListStyle").sortable({
 helper:'clone',
 revert:true
}).disableSelection();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use live() instead of normal binding, but Elte Hupkes solution rocks!!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.menu_group tbody a').click(function(){
    link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

This solution seems to be working for me. Now i can click on clickables inside sortable elements.

Note: `".menu_group tbody"` is `.sortable();`