# Prevent click events on Sortable of jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, sorting, click, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable, draggable and click events binded to the same DOM element.

On sorting, I want the click event to be disabled.

I am using the following code for draggable, which works fine:

```
$('.selector').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
    ui.helper.bind('click.prevent', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }); 
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           ui.helper.unbind('click.prevent');
       },1000);
    }
});
```

I got the above example while going through SF a while back.

However, the same code doesnt work when I use it for sortable.

I found out the reason being that the `ui.helper` is `null` for sortable's stop function.

Any way that i can prevent click event on sorting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Sortable -- How can I cancel the click event on an item that's dragged/sorted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947195/jquery-ui-sortable-how-can-i-cancel-the-click-event-on-an-item-thats-dragged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery UI Sortable -- How can I cancel the click event on an item that's dragged/sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947195/jquery-ui-sortable-how-can-i-cancel-the-click-event-on-an-item-thats-dragged)