# jQuery UI sortable click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 list that are sortable (#sortable1 and #sortable2) and I made 2 `click()` functions to handle each sortable item click event (`$("#sortable1 li").click(function(){})` and `$("#sortable2 li").click(function(){})`).

I move 1 item from #sortable1 (for ex: Sort1 Item 2) list to #sortable2 list. The problem is when the item has moved to the #sortable2 and I try to click it, the triggered mouseevent is `$("#sortable1 li").click(function(){})` not `$("#sortable2 li").click(function(){})`.

Any suggestion so if I move item from sortable1 to sortable2 and click that item, the item trigger `$("#sortable2 li").click(function(){})`?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/yosafatade/zX3pX/12/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use `on()` see the update http://jsfiddle.net/zX3pX/13/

Comment: live() is deprecated - use .on()

Comment: If you have clickable items in the Sortable, also add the options `helper : 'clone',` on the Sortable Options to prevent fire the click event on dragging/sorting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947195/jquery-ui-sortable-how-can-i-cancel-the-click-event-on-an-item-thats-dragged

Answer (score 3):

I would use `.on` as `.delegate` has been superseded.  That way you attach the event to the list not the list item.

Use this:

```
$("#sortable1").on("click", "li", function(){
        $("#testClickSort1").html($(this).html());
});

$("#sortable2").on("click", "li", function(){
        $("#testClickSort2").html($(this).html());
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qkCcS/

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add a class to each `li` item of what table it is in. For instance

```
<li class='sort1'></li>
```

Then when you check `.click` on `$(".sort1")` and when you move the item run

```
$(this).removeClass("sort1");
$(this).addClass("sort2");
```

Comment: I've tried that way before, but the problem still occurs. the answer from @DavidMichaelHarrison and CrimsonChin is the appropriate answer.